# (Base) ClearCase lock main branch for checkins

Tags: clearcase

I would like to lock the **main** branch of a component so that others can't check in any changes that break existing functionality or API compatibility. I've done a `cleartool lock <element>@@/main` for all files in the component, but this also prevents checkout operations.

I've argued that checking out in a branch is still allowed, but I work in an environment with pretty primitive SCM practices, where an unnatural fear of branching exists. Is it possible to just lock the branch for checkins and still allow checkouts?

The only thing I can think about is setting a ClearCase trigger. Are there any better options out there?

Comment: "Component"? As in UCM component? Or are you using base ClearCase only?

Comment: @VonC Base ClearCase. I used the term Component since I've seen the term in some other publications. Is it a pure UCM term?

Comment: Yes, it is. UCM component.

Comment: Can you lock the branch instead of the elements? That will prevent checkout though (hence the use of branches)

Comment: @VonC Wouldn't that lock **main** for all files in the VOB? We use the same VOB for multiple libraries.

Comment: OK, then trigger seems to be a good alternative indeed.

Comment: @VonC Would library be the appropriate term for a set of files that are versioned together?

Comment: No, component is good, I just wanted to know which ClearCase you are using.

Comment: @VonC If you write this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I will (I am commuting by train at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [discussed in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000002915909&ps=100&tags=&query=&filter=), locking folders and elements is not ideal.

In order to enforce a policy without having to deploy it for every client, setting a trigger remains the best option.

That thread suggests (for checkout, but the same idea can apply to checkin)

> place a trigger on the directory to stop the checkout.
>   By default when you place an "element"  trigger on a directory it is applied to it's current elements and  future directory elements via its attachment list and inheritance list.

```
cleartool mktrtype  -ele -preop checkout -exec /path/to/script NO_CHECKOUT
cleartool mktrigger NO_CHECKOUT  /path/to/dir_name
```

In your case, the `/path/to/script` (a path that should be accessible by all clients) needs to check if the current branch is `/main` (using the [trigger environment variables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm#ref_mktrtype_refsect1_234654), like `CLEARCASE_BRTYPE`).